# How to edit grub config manually?

Tags: debian, usb, grub, debian-installer

I have a USB Debian installer and I would like to add a new menu item to the grub menu (Automated install with some boot parameters). I did find grub.cfg and I added my custom menu item but it does not show up in the grub menu. Rechecked the grub.cfg file, my menu item is still there so it did not get overwritten but it does not work.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run update-grub after editing?

Comment: No I did not. That would overwrite my grub.cfg file and I do not have grub-update command on my OS X. The installer has no live version so I cannot use that either. Also since I am trying to change the grub menu of the installer USB not an installed linux system I think it would fail (since there is not /etc folder on the USB).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. grub.cfg only used for creating other cfg files.
If you want to edit the existing menu items or add your own you have to edit menu.cfg and other cfg files included in menu.cfg (in my case it was txt.cfg for modifying text-based install menu item to have my custom boot parameters and to add a custom label).

Comment: You better add your stuff to as `cat <<EOF ... your menu ... EOF` in an executable script in `/etc/grub.d` (eg. `/etc/grub.d/07_MINE`) followed by `update-grub` instead of risking that the first kernel update wipe all your changes.

Comment: What version of grub/debian are you running? On my machine there's only a `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, no `menu.cfg` or other `.cfg` files.